# Issue exiting a while loop

Tags: python

*EDIT: I've culled this entry down to get rid of my overly-long explanation and various other edits because I've been able to boil this down to one issue.*

**Overview:** I'm building a blackjack program.

**Problem:** When the user hits 's' to stand, the program still loops back to the input, even though I'm trying to break the loop with 'hit_me = False'

**Testing environment:** I'm running this code in Replit.

I've tried dozens of configurations over many hours and I'm still wrestling with this. Any thoughts are appreciated!

(Also: I know some of this doesn't conform to the rules of Blackjack yet... I'll be refining this. For now I'm just trying to get my loops to work!)

```py
import random
game_over = False
while game_over == False:
  deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
  
  def draw_card():
    card = (random.choice(deck))
    return int(card)
  
  draw_card()
  
  ###First Deal
  dealer_card = int(draw_card())
  dealer_total = dealer_card
  player_card = int(draw_card())
  player_card2 = int(draw_card())
  player_total = (player_card + player_card2)
  print(f"The dealer gets: {dealer_card} \n")
  print(f"Your cards are: {player_card} and {player_card2} \nYour total is: {player_total} \n")
  if player_total == 21:
    print("Blackjack!")
    game_over = True
  elif player_total > 21:
    print("Bust!")
    game_over = True
  elif player_total < 21:
      hit_me = True
      while hit_me == True or player_total < 21:
        hit = input("Would you like to hit or stand? Press 'h' to hit or 's' to stand: ")
        if hit == 's':
          hit_me = False
          print("Stand test")
        elif hit == 'h':
          player_card = int(draw_card())
          player_total += player_card
          print(player_total)
          if player_total > 21:
            hit_me = False
            game_over = True
            print("Bust!")
          elif player_total == 21:
            hit_me = False
            game_over = True
            print("Blackjack!")
```

Comment: Check your printouts for what `player_total` is. It might be a value _over_ 21. So maybe your if check should be `>= 21`?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I tested your code and it seems to work just fine. Could you perhaps try testing the portion of code (isolated without any other code) you posted to see if it works on your end?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you don't seem to have a problem with the code but I would suggest you use [sys.exit('BlackJack')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) for it will graciously terminate the loop and std out the message for you.

Comment: @GinoMempin the usual rules of Blackjack state that anything over 21 is a bust, which is an automatic loss.  But the rules also say the only way to get 11 is with an Ace, which can be interpreted as either 11 or 1.  So two Aces could be 22, or 12, or 2.  This code is too simple to truly follow the rules.

Comment: Just a comment on style - `== True` and `== False` are redundant, and I hate seeing them.  Your while loop could easily be changed to `while not game_over:` and I would find it more readable.

Comment: "However, the program doesn't end.. it'll just hang there until I hit stop." - how are you running the script in the first place? From the command line? In an IDE? Online? It seems like your code works just fine with regards to stopping at exactly 21 (although, as others have pointed out, there's plenty of other problems with it)

Comment: Thank you for your comments... I updated the post with some revisions / clarifications. Any additional insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @Bruce
I've read your explanation above many times while testing the code on [replit](https://replit.com/)  and it is working just fine. So What is the problem!!?